# How to solve Elasticsearch 429 too many request error?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

**Problem-**

I have 30 data nodes of elastic-search which are suppose to consume a lot of data via a logstash consumer.
These 30 nodes are hosted on EKS and are experiencing `429 too many request error` because logstash is sending a huge batch of requests **(this is needed)**.

Out of these 30 nodes I see only one/two nodes where the requests are queued in the pool and rest 28 are not queuing anything at all, please find the details below
[image: details]

**Current Params**

- elasticsearch:

thread_pool:
write:
size: 9
queue_size: 30000

- logstash.outputs:

validate_after_inactivity => 0 
timeout => 500 
pool_max => 4000 
pool_max_per_route => 1500

- pipeline params:

  pipeline.batch.size: 8000
  pipeline.batch.delay: 6000 
  pipeline.workers: 30

**My Understanding**
I understand that my elasticsearch is unable to write as it is receiving a huge amount of data and I can reduce the throughput at logstash by reducing batch size/workers etc, but I want to tweak elasticsearch as I need this much of throughput via logstash

How should I solve this problem and make my elasticsearch queue more requests along which are distributed among the data clusters so that I don't run into 429 errors?

**Things I tried**
Increased-> queue_size, cpu, memory

Comment: This could be the case for imbalanced partitions. Can you confirm that your indices are distributed well across all the nodes ?

Answer (score 1):

The 429 Too Many Requests error in Elasticsearch indicates that the cluster is overloaded with too many requests and is unable to handle them efficiently.

> I understand that my elasticsearch is unable to write as it is
> receiving a huge amount of data

Correct. In current Elasticsearch cluster, shard architecture, index mapping, shard location, shard size, Elasticsearch can't handle to incoming write requests.
Increasing the pool size only increases the allowed documents in the queue for a while (default queue is 1k), after the queue is full the there will be rejection again.

To solve this issue I recommend you to check AutoOps product.
https://opster.com/

Opster will help you to understand what is missing.

Comment: Recommendation could be biased... better mention affiliation (i.e. employment) with Opster :)

Comment: The reason I'm writing a comment is because I want to get you a solution :).As far as I understand you already tried to set `pipeline.workers`, `pipeline.batch.size`, and `pipeline.batch.delay`. So adding a new node can help you to prevent this issue, but without seeing any metrics it's hard to say something. Please check the documentation below.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/tuning-logstash.html